# Jssor (nested slider): how to disable AutoPlay?

Tags: jquery, jssor

Does anyone know how to prevent the nested slider to start upon loading? I've tried entering "$AutoPlay: false" inside "var nestedSliderOptions", but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

source: http://www.jssor.com/download.html
examples-jquery > nested-slider.source.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'auto play' for the main slider and 3 child sliders by default. It is controlled by manual API call.

By removing following code, you will get what you want.

```
        function OnMainSliderPark(currentIndex, fromIndex) {
            $.each(nestedSliders, function (index, nestedSlider) {
                nestedSlider.$Pause();
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                nestedSliders[currentIndex].$Play();
            }, 2000);
        }

        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, OnMainSliderPark);
        OnMainSliderPark(0, 0);
```

Also, the [grid slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/grid-slider.html) is a variation of nested slider.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this plugin, but according to its documentation in [here](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html):

In order to prevent auto play you should call `$Pause()`

[image]

Just call this function right after you are creating the gallery

Comment: Touching the source code doesn't sound like a good idea - you can't know what else you've affected. good luck anyway